# SCHEME- comparing lists and returning only the values that do not appear in the second list

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I am having a hard time debugging this code and was hoping somebody might be able to help with pseudocode or examples of similar problems. Thank you ahead of time!

Define a non-recursive Scheme procedure *(remove-them2 lst n)* which returns a list of all elements of *lst* that do not appear in the list n.

Here is what I have so far:

```
(define (remove-them2 lst n)
  (if (null? lst)
     n
     (let ((tail (remove-them2 cons((cdr lst) (cdr n)))))
      (if (member (car lst) (car n) tail)
          tail
          (cons (car lst) (car n) tail)))))
```

Comment: This looks recursive. `remove-them2` calls `remove-them2`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there are several syntax errors in your solution, please take some time to study how to write procedures in Scheme and how to invoke procedures. To name a few:

- We don't call a procedure like this: `cons(...)`, the correct way is `(cons ...)`
- `cons` expects two arguments, but you're passing three
- `remove-them2` expects two arguments, but you're passing one
- `member` expects two arguments, but you're passing three
- The way you're building the output list is incorrect
- We don't need to ask for `(car n)`, we're interested in checking if an element is a member of the whole `n` list
- There's no need to have a `tail` variable here, it's easier if we just call the recursion directly; and anyway you're using `tail` incorrectly.

It's not clear what algorithm you tried to implement, but the actual solution is simple - although we'll have to rewrite the code from scratch to make it work:

```
(define (remove-them2 lst n)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (if (member (car lst) n)
          (remove-them2 (cdr lst) n)
          (cons (car lst) (remove-them2 (cdr lst) n)))))
```

**EDIT:** It's also possible to write a solution without using recursion:

```
(define (remove-them2 lst n)
  (filter (lambda (e) (not (member e n)))
          lst))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(remove-them2 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7) '(1 3 5))
=> '(2 4 6 7)
```

Comment: I need to write a program that does not use recursion in the solution. Such as using a map or something like that.

Comment: Hey @ÓscarLópez, the question posted does clarify to "Define a non-recursive Scheme procedure," which you failed to do. Rather than assist in modifying the posted code to change it into a non-recursive procedure, you rewrote the code as recursive as well, thus, not answering the question.

Comment: @Seudonym -- it is unclear what OP really wants: "_I am having a hard time debugging this code_" applies to OP's recursive attempt, and that is the valid part (though lacking debugging information) of OP question that this answer addresses. "_Define a non-recursive Scheme procedure_" is the assignment that OP has not yet attempted, but in the absence of an attempt this would just be a "write my code" request.

Comment: @Seudonym my answer covers the "debugging the code" request and now also added another alternative solution to cover the "non-recursive" requirement. The downvote is unwarranted.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which subset of the language you are allowed to use it's hard to answer this reasonably.

I'll assume that you want something which is not syntactically recursive (so you can't use a function with an accumulator: I'm not sure what the right word is for this), you are allowed to use `map` and `append`, but you're not allowed to use `filter` as that seems like such an immediate answer.

With those constraints here is how you can do this:

```
(define (remove-them2 l baddies)
  (apply append (map (lambda (e)
                       (if (memv e baddies)
                           '()
                           (list e)))
                     l)))
```

I think this is pretty artificial and horrible, but it works (in languages like CL it would not portably work however, which is why I think it's horrible).